# List<List<String>> with filter

Tags: java

I have a list which contains another list Which has String values

```
[ 
 ["ax", "BX", "CX_123"],
 ["ax", "BX", "CD_124"],
 ["ax", "BX", "CY_456"]
],
[ 
 ["ax", "BX", "CB_456"],
 ["ax", "BX", "CX_564"],
 ["ax", "BX", "CZ_345"]
],[ 
 ["ax", "BX", "CE_234"],
 ["ax", "BX", "CM_235"],
 ["ax", "BX", "CX_4534"]
]
```

I have to filter the list which start with CX_ value in the inner list

The result should look like:

```
[
   ["ax", "BX", "CX_123"],
   ["ax", "BX", "CX_564"],
   ["ax", "BX", "CX_4534"]
]
```

Comment: Your example input list is a `List<List<List<string>>>` (3-dimensions), while the output is `List<List<string>>` (2-dimensions). This involves not only filtering but also flattening. Anyway, please post your code to show what have you tried.

Comment: `list.stream().flatMap(List::stream).filter(inner -> inner.get(2).startsWith("CX_")).collect(Collectors.toList())`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use stream and filter to retrieve the result with condition

```
@Test
  public void test() {
    List<String> row1 = Arrays.asList("AA","BB","CX_11");
    List<String> row2 = Arrays.asList("CC","D","CD_11");
    List<List<String>> list = Arrays.asList(row1,row2);
    Assertions.assertEquals(row1, getFirstList(list,"CX_"));
    Assertions.assertEquals(row2, getFirstList(list,"CD_"));
  }

  public List<List<String>> getAllList(List<List<String>> list,String key){
    return list.stream().filter(this.contain(key)).collect(Collectors.toList());
  }
  
  public List<Map<String,String>> getListOfMap(List<List<String>> list,String key){
    Function<List<String>,Map<String,String>> convertListToMap = (l)->{
      Map<String,String> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();
      map.put("name", l.get(1));
      map.put("code", l.get(2));
      return map;
    }; 
    return list.stream().filter(this.contain(key)).map(convertListToMap).collect(Collectors.toList());
  }
  
  public List<String> getFirstList(List<List<String>> list,String key){
    return list.stream().filter(this.contain(key)).findFirst().get();
  }
  
  private Predicate<List<String>> contain(String key){
    return (l)-> l.stream().anyMatch(s-> s.contains(key));
  }
```

Comment: Shall I get the result like List with map
[
  {list[1]: list[2]},
  {list[1]: list[2]}
]

Comment: Can you share the code for that as well ?

Comment: your map example is quite strange, i can't get it ... Map should have key and value ... What is your expectation for key and value? Write down it and try implementing ... if you get stuck somewhere, post your code on stackoverflow.

Comment: My mistake
Shall I get the result like List with map
 [ 
   
      {name: list[1], code: list[2]}
   
 ]

ex:-
[
   {name: "BX", code:"CX_123"},
   {name: "BX", code: "CX_564"},
   {name:"BX", code:"CX_4534"}
]

Comment: this.contains(key) shows error cannot resolve method

Comment: I needs help again, there is a small change in the response.
the response should look like this
[
    {
     "code":"CX",
     "name":"CX_123"
    },
    {
     "code":"BX",
     "name":"CX_564"
    }
  ]
The code and name are attribute of another class ex: public Class Category{
private String code;
private String name;
}

Comment: i guess you want to have List<Category> right, then in this case, you can add more function convertListToCategory ... just like convertListToMap...

Comment: yes, you are right.
But I want to avoid make it distict
private Set<CategoryData> getSetObject(List<List<String>> list,String key, final int codePosition, final int nameposition){
  Function<List<String>,CategoryData> convertListToMap = (l)->{
   CategoryData obj =new CategoryData();
   obj.setCode(l.get(codePosition));
   obj.setName(l.get(nameposition));
   return obj;
  };
  return list.stream().filter(this.contain(key)).map(convertListToMap).collect(Collectors.toSet());
 }
This working fine, but it has duplicate data.

Comment: add more function distinct()...you can search how to use it. map(convertListToMap).distinct().collect...

Comment: Still getting the duplicate entries

Comment: can you post your full code in another question? Why the duplication is not removed? I or Others will help to check your code...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70506618/remove-duplicate-entry-using-stream

Answer (score -1):

```
You can do it by the following steps:
1. Declare a List<List<String>> will be returned
2. Foreach List<List<String>>, fetch each List<String>
       2.1. With each List<String>, foreach it, fetch each string
       2.2. If each string contains CX_ value, add this List<String> to the returned List<List<String>>
```